# Where are Git's pack files stored?

Tags: git, internals

I was recently excited to learn a bit about how Git stores its objects: namely, if you're looking for a commit (or tree, or blog) with a hash of `0f9f33986446bd8e832dac72177295bb75d3ec90`, you will find it in the `.git` directory of your project, under `objects/0f/9f33986446bd8e832dac72177295bb75d3ec90`. In other words, the first two letters of the hash are the subdirectory and the rest is the file name.

It's neat to see how the storage is done, but then I read about pack files in the [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/7_how_git_stores_objects.html).

Am I understanding the link correctly - are they not stored under this same directory structure? If not, where exactly are they stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `./objects/pack` (you may have to fire off a `git gc`). The packing stuff follows a rather neat heuristic which tend to pack things well in practice. You can quickly search for packs:

```
cd ${PROJECT}/.git && find . | grep pack
```

Comment: Why use that command to search for packs if they're all in .git/objects/pack? Why not just do `ls ${PROJECT}/.git/objects/pack`?

Comment: You are totally right, it was more seen as a hint on how to grab the packs if you don't know where they live.